# i am assessing the vegetated area. Is it in Metres or Sq meters?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am calculating NDVI through GEE, and I read some papers on research gate which described 0.2 as threshold value for healthy vegetation.

I write a code to calculate the area of healthy vegetation for my area of Interest which runs perfectly. Does  the area which calculates is in  meters or sq meters?

I share my code here to get help from experts.

```
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA') 
             .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2013-12-31')
             .filterBounds(SA)  
             .median();

//var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.3};

var extract= l8.clip(SA);

var ndvi= extract.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('NDVI'); 
var visParam = {
 min: -0.2,
 max: 0.8,
 palette: 'FFFFFF, CE7E45, DF923D, F1B555, FCD163, 99B718, 74A901, 66A000, 529400,' +
   '3E8601, 207401, 056201, 004C00, 023B01, 012E01, 011D01, 011301'
};


Map.addLayer(ndvi, visParam, 'NDVI image 2016');

//...........Histogram..l......
var histogram= ui.Chart.image.histogram(ndvi,SA,1000);
print(histogram,"Histogram");

//........threshold.....0.2 ......healthy vegetation......

var mask=ndvi.gt(0.2);
//Map.addLayer(mask, {}, 'mask');
var masked = ndvi.updateMask(mask);
Map.addLayer(masked,
  {min: -0.2,
 max: 0.8,
 palette: 'FFFFFF, CE7E45, DF923D, F1B555, FCD163, 99B718, 74A901, 66A000, 529400,' +
   '3E8601, 207401, 056201, 004C00, 023B01, 012E01, 011D01, 011301'
},'masked16');

var areaImage = masked.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())

// Calculate the area 
var stats = areaImage.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: SA.geometry(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

print('pixels representing ndvi: ', stats.get('NDVI'), 'meters');
 
//........export
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ndvi,
  description: 'Vegetation-2016',
  scale: 1000,
  region: SA,
  maxPixels:11e9,
});
```

Comment: The area which we retrieve is in meters or sq metres, kindly help

Comment: @BERA, This code runs perfectly, the area which i get is it in meters or sq meters? which i want to know and secondly i want to take experts help to check whether the code which i used is it ok for ndvi on threshold value.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you do some transformation, the area you will get is in square meters. However, the area you are getting right now is not correct, because the variable `areaImage` is not well calculated. Substitute such line by the following code:

```
var areaImage = ee.Image.pixelArea().updateMask(masked.mask());
```

Then, you will get the correct result in square meters.

Comment: ,can u tell me why we use update.Mask(masked.mask()) function,so that i can better idea

Comment: `ee.Image.pixelArea()` is an image in which the value of each pixel is the area of that pixel in square meters. Such image covers the whole region. However, you don´t want to calculate the total area within your region, you need it only where the NDVI is above 0.2. As `masked` contains only pixels above that threshold, you can use `masked` to mask `Image.pixelArea`.

Comment: Thanks sir for helping and clarify this concept.